# Inheriting constructor from parent class in scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to understand the syntax for inheriting one class from another and it seems I must announce the constructor parameters of the parent when I create the child?

**Why does this code not compile?**

```
  class Animal(name:String)
  class Dog extends Animal //Here is where compiler error occurs
```

**But this does**

```
  class Animal(name:String)
  class Dog(name:String ) extends Animal(name)
```

Is their a reason I must explicitly say `extends Animal(name)` and not just `extends Animal` and the constructor be implied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Scala Language Specification doesn't (as far as I can see) discuss the reasons, but providing an implied constructor would be a special case, and would arguably be less clear.

Note that you can do things like:

```
class Animal(name:String)
class Dog extends Animal("Dog")
```

and

```
class Animal(name:String)
class Dog(n1: String, n2: String) extends Animal(n1 + n2)
```

So the current behaviour accommodates a variety of patterns in a uniform and explicit way.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have two constructors for `Animal`:

```
class Animal(name:String) {
  def this() = this("unnamed")
}
```

Which of them would you expect `class Dog(name:String) extends Animal` to use?